# Checking for program installation and continuing script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this script which (I think) checks for existance of some programs and npm packages and then keeps doing stuff:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Functions ==============================================

function programa_instalado {
  # set to 1 initially
  local return_=1
  # set to 0 if not found
  type $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || { local return_=0; }
  # return value
  echo "$return_"
}

function paquete_npm_instalado {
  # set to 1 initially
  local return_=1
  # set to 0 if not found
  ls node_modules | grep $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || { local return_=0; }
  # return value
  echo "$return_"
}

function pregunta_node {
  if [ $1 == 1 ]; then
    $(echo "Node ya instalado")
  else
    $(curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -)
    $(sudo apt-get install -y nodejs)
    $(sudo apt-get install -y build-essential)
  fi
}

function pregunta_pyinstaller {
  if [ $1 == 1 ]; then
    $(echo "Pyinstaller ya instalado")
  else
    $(pip install pyinstaller)
  fi
}
function pregunta_zerorpc {
  if [ $1 == 1 ]; then
    $(echo "Zerorpc ya instalado")
  else
    $(pip install zerorpc)
  fi
}

# ============================================== Functions

# command line programs
$(pregunta_node $(programa_instalado node))
$(pregunta_zerorpc $(paquete_npm_instalado zerorpc))
$(pregunta_pyinstaler $(paquete_npm_instalado pyinstaller))
$(git clone some_url)
$(cd folder)
$(npm install --runtime=electron --target=1.7.9)
$(pyinstaller server.py --distpath dist ; rm -rf build/ ; rm -rf server.spec)
$(./node_modules/.bin/electron-packager . --overwrite)
```

The problem is That the excecution hangs forever. I don’t  know what could be possibly wrong

Comment: To have the errors in English would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The command substitution `$(...)` runs the command given inside the parenthesis and *puts the output back on the command line* (well, more or less, see in particular [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) if you ever actually need it.)

These do the same thing:

```
ls $(echo /bin)
ls /bin
```

In most cases, you don't want to run a command substitution by itself on a command line, but just run the commands normally (like you did with `ls node_modules | grep ...`). This is also the same as the previous ones, but just weird:

```
$(echo ls /bin)
```

In particular `$(cd somedir)` doesn't do anything useful, since the command substitution runs in a subshell, so changing the directory there doesn't affect the main shell.

This:

```
$(pregunta $(programa_instalado node))
```

First calls the function `programa_instalado`, which outputs (say) `1`. Then the shell tries to run the command `pregunta 1`, but judging by the error, there's no command with that name. If there were, *its output would also be executed as a command*.

Same for  `git` and `npm`, so either you really don't have those installed, or you should check that your `PATH` is sane.

Comment: yeah that was actually my bad. I didn't realize I hadn't written the according "pregunta_xxx". Now I've edited but the problem is that I don't get any response now, it just stays excecuting forever..

Comment: @user3754696, I suppose a large part of those command substitutions are still superfluous. You could put `set -x` at the start of the script to see the commands it actually runs, that should show you where it gets stuck